# Выдаёт -nan(ind)

Tags: c++, функции

В двух идентичных примерах коды работают по разному:

```
double f2(int n, double a, int x) {
a += sin(x * n);
if (1 < n){
    n--;
    f2(n, a, x);
}
else {
    return a;
}}
```

В данном случае выдаётся: -nan(ind)

```
void f3(int n, double a, int x) {
a += sin(x * n);
if (1 < n) {
    n--;
    f3(n, a, x);
}
else{
    cout << "third = " << a << endl;
}}
```

Здесь же ответ выдаётся правильный, хотя смысл решения тот же!!!
Почему в пером случае в качестве ответа какая-то фигня???
Функция вызывается со следующими параметрами: a = 0,n = 2,x = 2

Comment: В первом случае начальное значение **a == -nan ;** скорее всего. Вы же не показываете как вызываете с каким начальным значением. Скорее всего с неопределённым. Чтобы точно вам ответить, вы должны показать как вы вызываете с какими аргументами.

Comment: a = 0
n = 2
x = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае вы не возвращаете значение из функции *(нет команды **return** при условии `(1 < n)`)*. Возвращается именно неопределёнка. Нужно возвращать результат. Вот пример, всегда возвращаю. *Компилятор должен был вам сообщить предупреждением, а вы исправить.*

```
double f2(int n, double a, int x) {
  a += sin(x * n);
  if (1 < n){
    n--;
    a = f2(n, a, x); }
  return a; }
```

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо

Comment: Дела обстоят несколько хуже - остутствие возврата - UB